# How to Change Angular material Form-field Hight?

Tags: angular

The Form-field-input includes a hidden line  of errors if any
To make this line disappear so that the cell looks more compact and tiny, you can change the property of the form-field with a change in css like this :

`.mat-mdc-form-field-subscript-wrapper { height: 0 !important; }`

Answer (score 2):

The CSS solution setting the subscript height to 0 might work in specific cases, but this might lead to unwanted overlapping when a text is displayed in the subscript element.

There is also an input property for the `FormField` to configure whether space should be reserved for the subscript: it is called `SubscriptSizing`, and you can configure it as either `fixed` or `dynamic`. E.g.:

```
<mat-form-field subscriptSizing="fixed">
```

https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#SubscriptSizing
(introduced in Angular Material v15)

The `dynamic` value only shows the subscript if there is text to display, like a hint or an error message. Otherwise, the form field has a "compact" look. The `fixed` value always reserves space for the subscript.

In general, my advice would be to be very careful overriding global Angular Material styles and instead, try and stick to the defaults as far as possible. This saves a lot of headaches in the long run.